# Action on group $\operatorname{Ext}^i(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M})$ by scalar multiplication

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

Let $X$ be a proper scheme over field $k$ and $\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M}$ two invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Then $Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M}) \cong Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee}) \cong H^0(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$.

Therefore derived functors coinside as well as we assumed $X$ sufficiently nice:

$\operatorname{Ext}^i(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M}) \cong H^i(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$.

The right hand side has $ H^i(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ a natural structure of a $k$ vector space, therefore we can talk about subspaces, multiplication by scalars form $k$ and the whole other basic linear algebra stuff.

On the other hand the Abelian group $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M})$ has an interpretation as set of all extension classes

$$0 \to \mathcal{L} \to ? \to \mathcal{M} \to 0$$

where two classes are considered in  $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M})$ as equal if there exist commutative diagram between the two exact sequences such that the vertical arrows between $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ are identities and the middle vertical arrow a isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

QUESTION 1: by $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M}) \cong H^1(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ the Ext-group is also endowed with structure of a $k$ vector space and I'm asking if there is a nice description how two extension classes in $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M}) $ differ from each other /or related to each other if their corresponding elements in $H^1(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ differ by a multiplication by a scalar $a \in k^*$:

in other words if

$$0 \to \mathcal{L} \to E_1 \to \mathcal{M} \to 0$$

and

$$0 \to \mathcal{L} \to E_2 \to \mathcal{M} \to 0$$

are two representers of two extension classes in $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M})$ and the vectors $v_{E_1}$ and $v_{E_2} \in H^1(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ lie on the same line $k \cdot v_{E_1}$:

i.e. there exist a $a \in k^*$ with $v_{E_2}=a \cdot v_{E_1}$, is there a meaningful contruction between $E_1$ and $E_2$ in $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M})$ relating them to each other in dependence of $a$?

In other words how the two exact sequences of $E_1$ and $E_2$ are in this case related to each other in sophisticated way reflecting that their corresponding vectors in $v_{E_1}$ and $v_{E_2} \in H^1(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ are only differ by a scalar.

Or more generally, how the action of $k$ on by scalar multiplication 
$H^1(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$
can be transfered to an action on 
the exact sequences representing extension classes
from $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M})$?

QUESTION 2:

How to see that the $0$  in 
$\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M})$
(the neutral element of this
Abelian group)
corresponds to the class of splitting extension

$$0 \to \mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{L} \oplus \mathcal{M}
 \to \mathcal{M} \to 0$$

I often saw in comments/ remarks on this issue that
people just say 'that's because the two objects are
canonical' from both viewpoints: in a vector space
as well extension classes.

But I nowhere found a "clean" constructive argument 
why this identification is true diving in explicit
machinery how thegroup elements of the Ext^1
group are identified with extension classes.

Comment: The category of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules is a $k$-linear abelian category, so $\operatorname{Ext}^i(\mathscr{L},\mathscr{M}) $ is a $k$-vector space by definition. Your questions would be a better fit at MSE.

Comment: @abx: Please, read the question a bit more carefully. I understand that $\operatorname{Ext}^i(\mathscr{L},\mathscr{M})$ abstractly inherits from $H^i(X, \mathcal{M}\otimes  \mathcal{L}^{\vee})$ the $k$-vector space structure. Well, abstractly that's of course clear. The point is that I want see what explicitly happens with a representing element of extension class when the inherited $k$-action acts on it. ie how it "deforms" from the initial representing element. That is, "what happens inside", not "if something happens in well defined way"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remark. Exact sequence $0 \to L \to E \to M \to 0$ corresponds to $Ext^1(M,L)$, not to $Ext^1(L,M)$.

Q1. $a \in k^\times$ acts on $Ext^1(L,M)$ via pullback along $a:L \to L$ or via pushout along $a: M \to M$.

Q2. There are two options: either one can check that the split sequence is the neutral element for the addition, or that in the long exact sequence
$$
0 \to Hom(L,M) \to Hom(L,L \oplus M) \to Hom(L,L) \to Ext^1(L,M)
$$ 
the element $1_L \in Hom(L,L)$ goes to 0.

Comment: Do you know a recommendable reference where it is explaned why this inherited action by scalar multiplication induce exactly the pullback resp pushout. Up to now I nowhere found a homological algebra book treating exactly this point.

Comment: This is a good exercise. For instance, you can easily deduce this from the above exact sequence.

Comment: Another remark: probably your hint on second way to show that that $L \oplus M$ corresponds to $0$ shold be beginn with applying $Hom(-,L)$ instead of $Hom(L,-)$ to the sequence, right? I learned this topic on that way that in general if $0 \to L \to X \to M \to 0$ is a ex sequence then it's corresponding class arrise as image of $id_L$ of the boundary map after application of $Hom(-,L)$ and forming the long exact sequence

Comment: ...and a question on your hint on the verification about what kind of action is induced by $k$: Essentially this follows simply from the fact that the map $Hom(L,L) \to Ext^1(L,M)$ in compatible the $k$-multiplication; ie it's a $k$-morphism. That was the spice in your hint, right? More precisely, in addition we have to exploit the naturality of the boundary map...

Comment: more concretly we write an arbitrary sequence $0 \to L \to E \to M \to 0$ draw a vertical arrow $a: L \to L$ (=the multiplication by $a \in k$) and obtain pullback $a^*E$. Thus we obtain a commutative diagram between the sequence $0 \to L \to E \to M \to 0$ and $0 \to L \to a^*E \to M \to 0$ above conncted by the vertical maps. Then we apply $Hom(-,L)$ and compare the classes in $Ext^1(M,L)$ in the related commutative square. I think that is it?

Comment: The functor $Hom(-,-)$ has two arguments, you can derived with respect to any of these, and the results $Ext^i(-,-)$ are known to be isomorphic. Therefore, if you are interested in $Ext^1(L,M)$ you start with an exact sequence $$0 \to M \to E \to L \to 0$$ and either apply $Hom(L,-)$ to get a morphism $Hom(L,L) \to Ext^1(L,M)$, or apply $Hom(-,M)$ to get $Hom(M,M) \to Ext^1(L,M)$.

Comment: Could you take couple of minites to look through if I have implemented your hint on my QUESTION 1 regarding the scalar action of an arbitrary $a \in k^*$ on $Ext(L,M)$ correctly? Since I can't draw commutative diagrams in comments I wrote my approach as an answer below:

Answer (score 1):

That is we start with an arbitrary extension $0 \to M \to e_2 \to L \to 0$ represented by the class of the image $\Phi_{e_2}:=\delta(id_L)$ with respect the delta-map in lower row in second diagram below and it's pullback extension $e_2$ in the upper row. Now we want determine that the extension $\overline{e_1}$ is represented by multiplication $a \cdot \Phi_{e_2} =: \Phi_{e_1}$.

We apply $Hom(L,-)$ to diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>  >> M @>  >> e_1 @>a^{-1} >>  L @> >> 0\\
@VVV  @VVV  @VVV  @VV\cdot{a}V \\
0 @>  >> M @>  >> e_2 @> >>  L @> >> 0 
\end{CD}
$$

and obtain

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Hom(L, E) @>  >> Hom(L,L) @>\delta  >> Ext(L,M) @> >>  \\
@VVV  @VV\cdot{a}V  @VVV  \\
Hom(L,\overline{E}) @>  >> Hom(L,L) @>\delta  >> Ext(L,M) @> >> 
\end{CD}
$$

That's a diagram of $k$-vector spaces. As you explaned in the answer the extension $e_1$ is forced to be the pullback of $e_2$: i.e. $e_1= a^*e_2$. $k$-linearity and commutativity of the maps imply $a \cdot \Phi_{e_2}=a \cdot \delta(id_L) = \delta(a \cdot id_L) = \Phi_{e_1}$. So $e_1=a e_2$. Is this the correct result of the $k^*$ action by scalar multiplication on $Ext(L,M)$? Or do I have somewhere implemented your hints on my question 1) in wrong way?

Comment: In the first diagram take both lines to be the original extension (with the arrow $E \to L$ in the top line modified by $a^{-1}$) and the vertical arrows to be 1, 1, and $a$. Note that the diagram commutes and is the pullback diagram (pullback of the bottom line with respect to the right vertical arrow). Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be the extensional classes of the lines. Consider the second diagram, the vertical arrows on it are induced by the morphisms of the second argument, hence they are $1$, $a$, $1$. The commutativity of the second square then reads as $ae_2 = e_1$. This is what you need.

Comment: @Sasha: I have adjust my elaboration of your argument above to your notations. Hope, it's correct now?